# Are we allowed to hold objects without a data structure?

Tags: python, data-structures

I am writing code to solve the following very basic CodeChef problem: https://www.codechef.com/problems/FLOW006

I have looked at a number of solutions and they follow the same logic as below:

```
T = int(input())

for i in range(T):
    ans = 0
    x = input()
    for digits in x:
        ans += int(digits)

    print(ans)
```

I am used to coding on Leetcode and things are so different with respect to the input. In any case, my question is where we have the for loop and `"x=input()"` ; which I understand creates however many instances of inputs as the value of T.

However, what/where are we storing these values/inputs?? Usually I'm used to appending them in an array or list [] then working with this data structure, but it seems here there is no data structure? Is this a generally accepted way to code? Or am I missing something?

Comment: They're not being stored anywhere, they're being processed, printed, and thrown away each time through the loop. If you needed them after the loop then you would need to store them in a list or such.

Comment: I see! Okay thanks